# How can I compare the predictive power or association of two variables of different nature?

Tags: predictive-models, ordinal-data, continuous-data, discrete-data, association-measure

I am dealing with the following problem:

We have 3 variables:

1. A continuous variable (0 to 1), that is a scoring for people.
2. A discrete variable, offered by a partner, in the range 1..10. That is also an Scoring variable.
3. A discrete ordinal variable in the Range 1..5, which is the score given by the public authorities, and functions similar to a "target / test" variable, given it's origin. Anyone with this score >=3 is considered "bad"

The thing is that I have to check if **wether the first or the second variable is better to predict / is more associated with the 3rd variable**

Given the nature of the variables I was thinking of the following approaches:

1. Compute Kendall Tau and/or Spearman R rank coefficient of 1 and 2 with 3, and compare them.
2. Make 3rd variable binary (with the value >= 3 threshold), train a classifier with ONLY ONE of each variables, and compare different classifier metrics.

I wanted to know if my proposals are fundamentally flawed or not. And what do you think would be a good approach to make the comparisson that I am in need of.

---

#### EDIT 1

**In response to @AJKOER**

So, no, they are **not intended to be combined**.

The 2nd variable is a **new one** that intends to be better than the 1st one and replace it, so I should determine wheter or not should we start considering this new variable.

The **3rd variable** is the one I think @AJKOER is referring to as **"a sample of ratings by accepted experts"**. Meaning that I have to take it as "the truth" or a parameter for comparisson. (sorry that I don't actually find a proper word to express what I mean).
Then see if the 1st or 2nd  is more associated with it (be it in and ordinal way or in the binary way explained aboved, both results are useful for me)

---

Thank you very much in advance for any help,
If more information is needed or something is no clear, please let me know.

Comment: More details please, a predictive variable should be able to forecast something concrete. If all 3 variables are intended to be combined for a judgement index, then one still needs a sample of ratings by accepted experts (judges) and compare their results to individual and combined forms of the individual rating indexes.

Comment: @AJKOER I tried to clarify about your comment, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both Kendall Tau and Spearman R rank are all kind of correlation indicators, each has it's own assumptions and focus. But none of the focuses is about "prediction power".

Prediction power is influenced by not only correlations, but also assumptions implied in your model. From this perspective, your second approach, which in essence is a model selection process, make more sense.

While taking the second approach, I recommend using "cross validated prediction error" as the selection criteria, it is a good approximation to "expected prediction error", which directly measures the prediction power.

Comment: Thank you for the comments!
It's true that my analysis was assuming that a higher correlation/association between the two would necessarily imply a stronger prediction capacity, which is an oversimplification! 
Thanks again!